# What are good command line utilites in Windows to monitor processes?

Tags: windows, monitoring

I would love to have ps, top, and time on Windows to monitor the performance of a developed C++ application on Windows from a remote shell.  Are any of these available?

Comment: Sounds like this Belongs on serverfault.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`PsList`** from SysInternals (now owned by Microsoft) for `ps` and `top`.

For `ps`-like behaviour, simply:

```
pslist
```

For `top`-like behaviour:

```
pslist -s
```

**`timeit`** from the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools for `time`.

Answer (score 5):

Builtin to Windows is "tasklist /s remotepc"

Comment: outstanding :) +1

Comment: How did I ever miss this command?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't powershell has some of those ? See here (comparison table)

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin has 'time', but no 'top' and its 'ps' looks lame.

Answer (score 0):

ProcessExplorer by Sysinternals is very impressive.